# Enabling debug toolbar and toggle status caused HTTP error

Tags: toolbar, debug

I had enabled a Debug Toolbar.
Got a menu on the right side, where you could toggle the status of modules installed. Now I just wanted to see what it would show, and clicked the first one, I think it said Magento. Cannot reproduce anymore.
Now I cannot access the site anymore, only the backend.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `app/etc/modules` then open "Themodule_Name.xml", set `active` to "false" instead of "true". Then delete the `var/cache` folder, and reload the page

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. However, I did as you said, set active to false in Magneto_Debug.xml and deleted the va/cache folder and reloaded the page but it does not help.

Comment: What's the URL of your store?

Comment: testshop.etkserver.nl

Comment: I have it back! No idea why after a while it works. But thank you so much!

Comment: To avoid any trouble in the future, if it's a **dev** environment, you can safely turn off all the caches (they will also be out of your way)